# Example Environment Indented

Tags: mdframed, examples

I am trying to use an "example environment" defined using the mdframed package as follows (taken from another answer here on StackExchange):

```
\newmdtheoremenv[
hidealllines=true,
leftline=true,
innerbottommargin=6pt,
linewidth=4pt,
linecolor=gray!40,
leftmargin=0pt,
innertopmargin=-6pt,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{example}{Example}
```

However, when I use it, it's indented. I want it not to be indented and I want the text "Example #" to be bolded. How can I modify the environment to make this happen?

Thanks so much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Also, please provide a link to the other answer and it is only polite to give the person who wrote that code credit for it. (It is also probably required by the licence on the code but I think courtesy is a stronger reason, myself.)

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What exactly is indented?

Answer (score 2):

I think that by "indented" you mean that the text width inside the environment is less than the `\textwidth` for the document; adjusting `leftmargin` will give you the desired result. The title "Exercise #" is already in boldface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdtheoremenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  innerbottommargin=6pt,
  linewidth=4pt,
  linecolor=gray!40,
  leftmargin=-14pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As an alternative, I'd like to suggest you to use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{texample}[1][]{
  breakable,
  boxsep=0pt,
  leftrule=4pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  before skip=\topsep,
  after skip=\topsep,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!40,
  oversize,
  title={Example~\thetcbcounter},
  fonttitle=\normalfont\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  fontupper=\itshape,
  detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\hspace{0.5em}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{texample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{texample}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]